# how to print subsequently in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, for-loop

I want to print the inputted string subsequently.
My code:

```
text = input()
for i in text:
    print(i)
```

Input:

```
ENG
```

My output:

```
E
N
G
```

The output I want:

```
E
EN
ENG
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    print(text[:i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    print(text[:i+1])
```